# MouseListener overriding Paint Component

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, paintcomponent, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a a program in MVC architecture which simply opens a frame (JFrame) with some certain design and when clicked somewhere with a mouse simply prints to the console : "sth" notifying that the action went through successfully but it seems that the Input.java class when added to the frame before the Ouput.java class is overridden by the latter and disables MouseListener, or the former overrides the latter where you're able to activate MouseListener executing a certain program when clicked on the frame but doesn't show the design  made in Output

Here are the mentioned  class files:

input.java:

```
package MouseListenerTest;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Input extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    Input()
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Ej Adiiiii");
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
    {

    }
}
```

Output.java

```
package MouseListenerTest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Output  extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }
}
```

Frame.java

```
package MouseListenerTest;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame
{
    Frame()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Output());
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Input());
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("MouseListener test");
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package MouseListenerTest;

public class Controller 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Frame();
    }
}
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to learn at least the basics about [laying out components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

the problem in your code is because the way you added the elements to frame and I changed to a `GridLayout` and added them to frame to see both:

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
frame.getContentPane().add(new Output());
frame.getContentPane().add(new Input());
```

[more info about Layout Manager](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-layout-manager)

Comment: You're mixing up GridLayout and BorderLayout.